Создание listOf из консоли
В общем, нужно создать listOF по данным, которые вводятся в консоль. Если с массивами это делается понятно: var array = IntArray(readln().toInt(), {readln().toInt()}), то как это делается с listOf ?
Вот пример задачи:
На вход программе подаётся число n - длина списка. Затем - n элементов списка, каждый на новой строке. Напишите программу, которая создаёт список из этих чисел и выводит сумму их квадратов
Sample Input 1:
4
1
2
3
4

Sample Output 1:
30


Ну типа var list = List(readln().toInt(), {readln().toInt()}). listOf не для этого случая.

Insolor, спасибо. Вроде ок, завтра буду ковырять)
